# How can I add points on top of this choropleth?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
MERGED2014_15_PP <- read_csv("/MERGED2014_15_PP.csv")
a1 = subset(MERGED2014_15_PP, !is.na(SATMTMID), !is.na(SATVRMID))
a2 = subset(a1, !(SATMTMID=="NULL" | SATVRMID=="NULL"))
a3 = a2 %>% group_by(STABBR) %>% summarize(SATMTMIDavg = mean(as.numeric(SATMTMID)), SATVRMIDavg = mean(as.numeric(SATVRMID)))
a4 = subset(a3, !(STABBR=="PR" | STABBR=="VI" | STABBR=="DC"))
a5 = data.frame(state = tolower(abbr2state(a4$STABBR)), SATMTMIDavg=a4$SATMTMIDavg, SATVRMIDavg=a4$SATVRMIDavg)
# map_id creates the aesthetic mapping to the state name column in your data
a6 <- ggplot(a5, aes(group = 2, map_id = state)) + 
  # map points to the fifty_states shape data
  geom_map(aes(fill = SATMTMIDavg), map = fifty_states) + 
  expand_limits(x = fifty_states$long, y = fifty_states$lat) +
  coord_map() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  theme(legend.position = "right", 
        panel.background = element_blank())
a7 = a6 + aes(group = 2, fill2 = SATVRMIDavg) + scale_fill_colorplane() +
  theme(legend.position = "right")
a7
```

NOTE: Some of this code comes from http://www.et.bs.ehu.es/cran/web/packages/fiftystater/vignettes/fiftystater.html

I have generated a choropleth with the above code and I am now trying to add to this points from MERGED2014_15_PP for each institution. I am able to generate a data frame with the longitudes, latitudes, and institutional names. However, I am unable to add them using geom_point and am getting an error that the aes for the geom_point is not of the same length as the dataset, even though I have it grouped separately and I have `aes.inherit = FALSE`. What else could I try?

Comment: First, without sample data, it is difficult to help you.
Second, where in your code do you use the geom_point?

Comment: I removed it, but when I tried it, it was at the very end with a7. The data is too large to upload, but can be found from the Department of Education.

Comment: Could you upload a sample? Say 10 observations?
Or point us to the url?

Nonetheless, aes.inherit = FALSE might mean that you did not provide the geom with required coordinates or scales. In the case of geom_point, you need to at least point to x and y coordinates.

This can be set in the call to ggplot(). But in you code, ggplot()'s aes lacks isntructions for x and y.

Comment: I did. However, the issue was that it was confused by the original z, y given for the choropleth. The link is: https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/college-scorecard